# .htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters (Wordpress) Multisite Install

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues with a Multisite WordPress install, 500 error. It came around after installing w3 cache plugin. I looked around on here for bad flag delimiter questions and it seems the most likely problem is something extra that is not needed. But I don't know what to look for. Would be very appreciative to gain some knowledge on my problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be cuplrit:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
```

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

As `RewriteRule` syntax doesn't allow inline comments.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The suggested fix worked and my website is back up. Cheers!